# Login button redirects to two pages. For first time loginers, it redirects to agreement page, and for rest, it redirects straight to home?

Tags: javascript, node.js, cypress

My login functionality testing does this:

1. Type username
2. Type password
3. click login button
4. check for agreement page

My POM for login page:

```
class loginPage {
  
  fillUsername(value) {
    cy.get('[id=username]').clear().invoke('val', value);
    return this;
  }

  fillPassword(value) {
    cy.get('[id=password]').clear().invoke('val', value);
    return this;
  }

  clickLogin() {
    //cy.intercept('/portal/api/login').as('login')
    cy.contains("Login / S'identifier").click();
  }

  checkForAgreementPage(){
    const path ='/license-agreement'
    cy.wait(500)    // <- All the problem is here in this line
                    // If I comment this line cy.url() yields current page's url

    cy.url().then(($url) => {
      cy.log($url)
      if ($url.includes(path)) {
        //cy.log('Clicked')
        cy.get('[type=button]').contains('Accept').click();
      }
    });
  }
}
export default loginPage;
```

My custom function command.js:

```
Cypress.Commands.add('login', (username, password) => {
   lp.fillUsername(username);
   lp.fillPassword(password);
   lp.clickLogin();
   lp.checkForAgreementPage();
});
```

My spec file:

```
  it('TC01 - Login with valid data as wholesaler', () => {
    cy.login(id.username, id.password);  // for valid data
    cy.visit('/users');
    cy.logout();
  });

  it('TC05 - Login with username but no password ', () => {
    cy.login(id.username, id.password); // For invalid data
    cy.expected('span', 'Invalid username or password');
  });
```

How can i remove wait function from POM login page? and wait till url is changed?

Also, I've tried to intercept 'api/login' and waited for it to load, but then this will fail the other tests where I am testing failed login scenarios

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***I've tried to intercept 'api/login' and waited for it to load, but then this will fail the other tests where I am testing failed login scenarios***

Intercept is the best option IMO, but I can see with your POM structure you sometimes need to wait for the alias and sometimes not.

Easiest way forward is making wait on intercept optional,

```js
Cypress.Commands.add('login', (username, password, waitForUrl = false) => {
   lp.fillUsername(username);
   lp.fillPassword(password);
   
   cy.intercept('/portal/api/login').as('login')  // ignored if not waited on
   lp.clickLogin();
   if (waitForUrl) {
     cy.wait('@login')
   }

   lp.checkForAgreementPage();
});


it('TC01 - Login with valid data as wholesaler', () => {
  cy.login(id.username, id.password, true);  // for valid data
  cy.visit('/users');
  cy.logout();
});

it('TC05 - Login with username but no password ', () => {
  cy.login(id.username, id.password); // For invalid data
  cy.expected('span', 'Invalid username or password');
});
```

Shows one of the problems when you try to encapsulate things too much, the logic gets a bit fixed in the "happy path".

Answer (score 0):

You may want to have two separate methods to handle first time users and existing users to handle your scenario.

By the looks of it, it seems you are only validating the `pathname` of the url in your `checkForAgreementPage()` function. Although the following does not take into account of other scenarios you may have in your suite as there is a if statement which can entail different scenarios, you can remove the `cy.url()` portion and do the following instead:

```
checkForAgreementPage(){
    const path ='/license-agreement'

    // The should will trigger retrying the previous command so cypress will
    // continuously check for the pathname to include the path until the
    // command timeout, so you don't have to have an explicit wait
    cy.location('pathname')
      .should('include', path)
      .then(cy.log) // can comment out if you don't want to log the pathname
    // now you can click on the accept button
    cy.get('[type=button]').contains('Accept').click();
    });
```